# How to cancel a script running in the scheduler on a Synology NAS?

Tags: synology

I have a script running in the scheduler on a Synology NAS. How can I cancel it? I don't see a cancel option on the menu.

Comment: `ssh` into it as `root`, find the PID with `top` or `ps aux` then `kill -15 <PID>`.

Comment: Thanks but that's gibberish to me - no easier way? I suppose I could reboot the NAS?

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you reboot the device, the script is going to be interrupted.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? Which solution did you adopt? If you are still stuck, please provide more details.

Comment: After going down the SSH rabbit hole I decided to reboot the NAS.

Answer (score 3):

If you have absolutly no clue how to find the script PID because you don't know what to search for...
In Task Settings you can save the Output and specify output folder!
In this folder you can see your Taskname, in the subfolder is the Identifier for the task, this random*?* number string can easily be used with ps aux | grep XXXXXXXXXX to find the PID

Example:

```
Haldi@NAS:~$ ps aux | grep 1571863198
Haldi    12675  0.0  0.0  23128   972 pts/3    S+   23:07   0:00 grep --color=auto 1571863198
root     26976  0.0  0.0  18056  1532 ?        S    22:39   0:00 sh -c '/volume1/PUBLIC/Dateien/NASStuff/CPU_Temp_Influx/1571863198/script.log' > '/volume1/PUBLIC/Dateien/NASStuff/CPU_Temp_Influx/1571863198/output.log' 2>&1
root     26977  0.0  0.0  18092  1236 ?        S    22:39   0:00 sh -c '/volume1/PUBLIC/Dateien/NASStuff/CPU_Temp_Influx/1571863198/script.log' > '/volume1/PUBLIC/Dateien/NASStuff/CPU_Temp_Influx/1571863198/output.log' 2>&1
Haldi@NAS:~$ kill -15 26976
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `ssh` into it as `root`: `ssh root@<myNASaddress>`.
2. find the PID with `top` or `ps aux`:

   ```
   USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
   root     13748  0.0  0.3  28248  1888 ?        S<s  00:05   0:00 synoscgi
   ```

   You need to identify the task by looking at the `COMMAND` column, then take the number in the `PID` column. I don't know what the `COMMAND` name is going be in your case, you have to figure out the right line by looking for a name that makes sense, and taking into account the other info available, such as the `USER` it is run as, the `START` time, etc.
3. `kill -15 <PID>`: e.g. `kill -15 13748`. This command asks the process to terminate, possibly in a clean way. If this is not enough, do a `kill -9 <PID>`, which terminates the process.

**UPDATE** after OP's comment:

If you are looking for a really easy way, shutting down or rebooting the device is sure to do the job. This solution has the advantage of being applicable to a large spectrum of programs and operating systems.

Comment: For other's unfamiliar with SSH this looks like help:
https://zarino.co.uk/post/ds214se-under-the-hood/

Comment: You can access the Synology NAS via a Telnet/SSH client like PuTTY.

Answer (score 0):

Without root access you can:

1. Check full process name through SSH: ps aux | grep somethingyouneed

   example:
   ps aux | grep lifx

   root 22189 58.1  6.6  57552 16560 ? S < l 12:24 0:04 **mono lifx.exe**
2. Synology Control Panel => Task Scheduler => Create => Scheduler Task => User defined script
3. General => User = root
4. Task settings => User defined script = pkill -2 -f "NAME"

   NAME = value from step 1
5. Run the task manually or by schedule

Answer (score 0):

SSH is one way, if you don't want to do this (or don't have SSH terminal access enabled), there is an easier way.

1. Open Resource Monitor and locate your task and make a note of
   it's PID.
2. Create a Triggered, Disabled task called "Kill something
   with fire"
3. Set the script to run as root
4. In the script body put "kill "
5. Save the script, exit, right click and manually run the script.

I leave this script there, disabled, as it's easier than SSH into the NAS.